# Unable to reinstall compass after upgrade to MacOS Sierra

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, macos-sierra, compass

I had compass working fine with El Capitan, but the compass command was unavailable after upgrading to Sierra, and now I am unable to reinstall compass. Here is the text of the error from mkmf.log:

```
Applications/MAMP/Library/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -    I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib -L. -fstack-protector     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -lruby-static
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I have the most current version of XCode installed. I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by installing Ruby Version Manager:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /Users/yourusername/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

. . . and then reinstalling compass:

```
sudo gem install compass
```